# Which virtual machine is faster? VMware or Virtual box or?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware

My question is in subject line. which of the two is faster or is there a faster/better  choice?
TIA

Comment: Try them out yourself or buy the hardware you have to all the volunteers answering questions here. Maybe someone will have the time to do the testing. This is a question answer site for Ubuntu. Your question is not about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Both are about equally fast on most hardware.

The *better* choice is the one that you know how to properly install, use, and maintain.

Try both and decide for yourself which you prefer.